# Add class to menu on hamburger click

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, overlay

I have been going backwards and forwards.

I am using https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/ for the mobile hamburger animations.

The problem is, I click on the hamburger, the menu overlay opens. However, if you click the overlay it disappears without resetting the hamburger. The X remains.

Second problem, and one that I have been trying to fix with jQuery. This is my first time using it, so bear with me.

I have the menu fade in on scroll down, however, I have been trying to inject a 'remove' class, into the 'menu' class. So that I can set the CSS to display none. At the moment it is on top of the overlay and does not look good.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".hamburger").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
  });
});

$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);

  open = false;
});

var $hamburger = $(".hamburger");
$hamburger.on("click", function(e) {
  $hamburger.toggleClass("is-active"), $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
  // Do something else, like open / close menu
});
var $hamburger = $(".hamburger");
$hamburger.on("click", function(e) {
  $hamburger.removeclass("is-active");

});

$(".hamburger").click(function() {
  $('#menu').addClass('remove');
});

$(".hamburger").click(function() {
  $('#menu').removeClass('');
});

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#menu').fadeIn(500);
      } else {
        $('#menu').fadeOut(500);
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.hamburger {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  transition-property: opacity, -webkit-filter;
  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-property: opacity, filter, -webkit-filter;
  text-transform: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.hamburger:hover {
  opacity: .7
}
.hamburger-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px
}
.hamburger-inner {
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -2px
}
.hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-inner:after,
.hamburger-inner:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #000
}
.hamburger-inner:after,
.hamburger-inner:before {
  display: block;
  content: ''
}
.hamburger-inner:before {
  top: -10px
}
.hamburger-inner:after {
  bottom: -10px
}
.menu-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: 4;
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  float: right
}
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 .3rem 0
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: .5rem !important;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent
}
nav ul li:hover {
  border-top: 3px solid #FFC3AF
}
nav ul li a {
  color: #2d2d2d;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="hamburger hamburger--elastic" tabindex="0" aria-label="Menu" role="button" aria-controls="navigation">
    <div class="hamburger-box">
      <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-scroll">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="navigation">
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul class="wrap-nav">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- end overlay - wrap -->
</div>
<!-- end overlay -->
```

Comment: Would you like to kindly make a snippet out of your code? Never mind, doing it myself.

Comment: Kindly make the snippet working... Thanks.

Comment: Hi Praveen, Thank you for your help. Could you help me understand what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Tommy, still I am unable to understand the issue you are facing... I guess I can help if you show me a perfect place where it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, apologies, I wasn't sure on how to put the information on the website. So put up everything. The website is atonestyling.co.uk, this is where the problem is.

Comment: Ah... That's nice. Lemme check now. So I went to the website. What am I looking for?

Comment: If you put the screen into ipad size, you will see the hamburger to left, if you click on it the overlay opens. But if you click the pink it will close the overlay but not reset the hamburger

Comment: Ah... Right... I could see that.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it out and I got the solution. You have this code, just make a few changes:

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);   
  // Add this:
  $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
  open = false;
});
```

You just need to toggle this class: `is-active` for the `.hamburger`. Another thing is, the error you have is:

```
$hamburger.removeclass("is-active");
//---------------^ Should be C not c.
```

The above is a typo. Change it to:

```
$hamburger.removeClass("is-active");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not realise that that would have such a difference.

Comment: Hi Praveen, I have got it working on the click of the overlay. 

But if I add this:

$hamburger.removeClass("is-active");

The overlay does not stay open?

Comment: Tommy, lemme have a look.